# How do I point git HEAD to a particular ref using the jgit library?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I want to update HEAD programmatically without performing a checkout or rebase on a non-bare repo.

I want the working tree and index to be unchanged after the operation.

**EDIT**

I need to update the symbolic target of HEAD, not the commit ID of the current target of HEAD.  This is more like a checkout than anything else, except I can't use `org.eclipse.jgit.api.CheckoutCommand` because it requires that I update paths, but I don't want to touch the working tree. `org.eclipse.jgit.api.CreateBranchCommand` is also inappropriate because it expects a particular starting point, which doesn't exist because I'm creating an orphan branch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me: [`RefUpdate.link()`](http://jgit.info/javadoc/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/RefUpdate.html#link%28java.lang.String%29).

Example:

```
Result updateHead(
    Repository repo, String newHead, boolean force, boolean detach
) throws IOException {
    RefUpdate refUpdate = repo.getRefDatabase().newUpdate(Constants.HEAD, detach);
    refUpdate.setForceUpdate(force);
    return refUpdate.link(newHead);
}
```

The answer is buried in about 5 places in the jgit source code.

Three api commands in jgit v2.0.0.201206130900-r update HEAD for you: clone, checkout, and rebase. Use one of those if it applies.

None of those apply: checkout and rebase would change the working tree and index.

Hopefully posting this question and answer will save others the time I had to spend on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `org.eclipse.jgit.api.ResetCommand` and set its mode to `SOFT`.

Comment: Perhaps asking to "update HEAD" is incorrect usage of the terminology. I'm actually creating an orphan branch, so `git reset --soft` is not what I want. I had already figured out how to create the parentless commit as advised [on the jgit-dev list](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jgit-dev/msg01397.html). The parentless commit I created should already have all the files in the working directory in the commit's tree. I didn't want to CheckoutCommand either because that would either cause a spurious DirCache update or I'd lose working dir files if my commit was incorrect.